# Given a value constrained with a member constraint, can I access the member as a first-class function?

Tags: f#

Is it possible to access a constrained member as a first-class function (given an object)? If so, what is the correct syntax to use?

```
  // Example: property getter as a first-class function
  type Test() =
     member x.Value = "42"

  let t = Test()
  let getter = t.get_Value // works as expected


  // now generically:
  let inline getGetter< ^a when ^a : (member get_Value : unit -> string)> item =
    // call getter
    let value = (^a : (member get_Value : unit -> string) item)
    // try to get getter as first-class function
    let getter = item.get_Value // doesn't compile: "Lookup on object of indeterminate type..."
    ()
```

Comment: Most likely unrelated, but it's inconsistent that `Test.Value` returns an `int` while `getGetter` is looking for `unit -> string`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks. Edited. (That was just a mistake in my example, but not the actual problem...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
  type Test() =
     member x.Value = "42"

  let inline getGetter< ^a when ^a : (member get_Value : unit -> string)> item =
    fun () -> (^a : (member get_Value : unit -> string) item)

  let t = Test()
  let getter = getGetter t
  let value = getter()
```